# C# Wrong Decimal Parse/Conversion

Tags: c#, parsing, type-conversion, decimal

Im trying to parse or convert the string `"3045.00"` (three thousand forty-five) but it always returns `304500.0` (three hundred four thousand five hundred).

The ways that i tried to:

```
Convert.ToDecimal("3045.00")

Decimal.Parse("3045.00")
```

Someone could help me? Thanks.

Comment: Your current culture is one which uses `.` as the thousands separator, not the decimal separator. Try parsing usnig a specific culture (such as the invariant culture), e.g. `decimal.Parse("3045.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: @canton7 you're completelly right! thanks a lot bud!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the `InvariantCulture` causes parsing to use the `.` character as the thousands separator (instead of the decimal separator)

```
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse("3045.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); //"3045.00"
```